# How to know if a mobile device is showing desktop?

Tags: javascript, mobile, desktop

I have seen very many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/1408137) asking how to detect if a device is mobile or not.  Generally, they fall into 3 categories:

1. Check the screen size/viewport
2. Check the User Agent
3. Use a library, such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to work around browser capabilities.

After implementing what I could, I still run across a situation which I have never seen asked or addressed; On many mobile browsers, there is a "Request desktop site" (Chrome) "Desktop Mode" (Dolphin) or "Desktop View" (HTC Sense).

[image]

I have chosen strategy #1 above, which works unless the page is viewed in desktop mode.  Implementing #2 has drawbacks (spoofing, uncatalogued agents, etc.).

Is there a reliable (cross browser) way to detect **Desktop Mode** on a mobile browser with Javascript?  jQuery or other libraries would be okay, but it should be based upon feature detection, rather than an array of User Agents.

Comment: Most of the websites which give a desktop mode option have different urls for mobile and desktop. Your question requires more modularity i think. We can store user's desktop mode preference in a cookie and loads stylesheets based user's preference.

Comment: @muratgozel, thank you for the reply.  Please note, I am not indicating a link within the website; rather, the mobile device can switch between "modes".  This option is part of the browser app, not the web page.

Comment: @Sablefoste , please check answer I had added, and mark as accepted answer if it helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on **@Shurvir Mori**'s answer, I narrowed down the code actually required for this approach without any third party code:

```js
/**
 * @return bool
 */
function isDesktopMode() {
    return window.innerWidth > screen.availWidth;
}
```

returns **true**, if

- Mobile device has **desktop mode=on**
- **Desktop** device has **browser window spanned over multiple screens**

returns **false**, if

- Mobile device has **desktop mode=off**
- Mobile device has **desktop mode=off** and browser in **popup view**
- **Desktop** device has **fullscreen browser** window
- **Desktop** device has **reduced size browser** window

Answer (score 0):

So, Finally I have **proven** method to detect this. There's little tricky but got Exact Solution.

---

### STEP 1

Install **device-uuid** Library , ( [Here already mentioned. How to install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71648227/5114465) )

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biggora/device-uuid/master/lib/device-uuid.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var user_configuration = new DeviceUUID().get();
    console.log(user_configuration);
</script>
// output
// {"isAuthoritative":true,"isMobile":true,......"resolution":[980,1104],"browser":"Chrome"}
```

---

### STEP 2

Detect device width

```
var curr_width = parseInt((window.innerWidth).toFixed());
```

---

### STEP 3

Now need to compare `curr_width` with `user_configuration.resolution[0]` (width)

If both are same then this is normal view and if not then it's  "**DESKTOP VIEW**" . attaching screenshot.

```
if(curr_width == user_configuration.resolution[0]){
   alert("normal_view");
}else{
   alert("desktop_view");
}
```

---

***Screenshot of Desktop Mode ON in mobile browser***
[image]

***Screenshot of Normal mobile view***
[image]

Comment: Interesting... the library is a little heavy (~23K, minified) just for checking if you are on a mobile device.  I will do a little research and see if it offers significant other benefits.

Comment: yes, It may be heavy for you, but as a solution, I applied so many stuffs from google, but only this one get me to exact solution. so it's ok for me, if it's 23Kb . :)

Comment: I reviewed the lib (which actually has nothing to do with this issue). The actual part needed can be narrowed down to two global variables:
`screen.availWidth` & `screen.availHeight`. No need for any kind of third party code.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way for a webpage to detect whether the device is actually a desktop computer or not. When "Request desktop site" is enabled, the phone acts just like a desktop does. One way to check this is to check the OS of the device. However, some phones use windows as their OS, so this won't work on windows phones.

Comment: Ok so obviously besides for Windows phones, how can this be done, and for Windows phones one can check the width