# How to get MAC address of client machine using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mac-address

I am trying to get the mac-address of client's machine whenever they click the button. (This is for office purpose only).

I have read multiple SO answer and in that they mentioned we can't do it using JavaScript but still am not satisfied with answer.

However I still managed to get client IP address using the below code but as the IP will be dynamic therefore I have to check for MAC address.

**Code to get the client IP address** .

```
 ngOnInit(){
         this.getUserIP(function(ip){
            console.log(ip)
        });
    }

getUserIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
            //compatibility for firefox and chrome
            // console.log("onNewIP" , onNewIP);
            // (<any>window).mozRTCPeerConnection 
            var myPeerConnection = (<any>window).RTCPeerConnection || (<any>window).mozRTCPeerConnection  || (<any>window).webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            var pc = new myPeerConnection({
                iceServers: []
            }),
            noop = function() {},
            localIPs = {},
            ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
            key;

            function iterateIP(ip) {
                if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
                localIPs[ip] = true;
            }

         //create a bogus data channel
         pc.createDataChannel("");

            // create offer and set local description
            pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
                sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
                    if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
                    line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
                });

                pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
            }, noop); 

            //listen for candidate events
            pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
                if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
                ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
            };
        }
```

**Why I want to get MAC address**

When the user signup in my software , later I want that user to make request from that machine only. Therefore I need the MAC address. Is this not possible?

Comment: You cannot get the MAC address from the machine where the browser is running on by executing Javascript (and thus also Angular.js) inside the browser. Access to this information is restricted due to the sandbox in which Javascript is executed.

Comment: This is the same answer provided in one of the SO answer . My another question is , there is node package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac . Then how they make it possible and how to use it ? @SunnyParekh

Comment: as far as I know, you can't read the mac address of the computer from js,
One possible solution is to generate an encrypted UUID from your server and sign it, you can store that UUID in a cookie and send it to your server on each request

Comment: for your second question, npmjs.com/package/getmac is for node.js, node is an interpreter of js, but node != js. https://www.educba.com/javascript-vs-node-js/

Comment: Your package _getmac_, first line's description : `Get the mac address of the current machine you are on`. It does __NOT__ get the Mac Address of a client's machine.

Comment: But i want see that does that user make the request from the machine that is allocated to him/her . Using UUID can it possible . If it is , please can you explain it in detail? @Dan

Comment: Ohh yes . Thank for correcting @Florian

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a UUID? @PushprajsinhChudasama

Comment: UUID is also know as _id ? is that only UUID ? @Dan

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: You can call it what you want, it's just something that identifies something unequivocally

Comment: That will not help me . @Dan

Comment: check out  this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692073/how-can-i-get-a-unique-device-id-in-javascript

Comment: The first thing that came to mind when I read the question was to create the application in Electron, then you can use some node module or similar to read system information.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the MAC address if the client and the server are in the same router. Or if there is only one router between the client and server.

I have done this in my Angular application.

First Client's IP using the below code.

```
   public async login(req: any, res: any) {
      getclientip(){
      const clientIp = req.ip;   
      return clientIp  ....
```

Second I use the arp command to get the ARP (Address resolution protocal) table, ( The Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) is used to map an IP address to a MAC address within a local network. When a device wants to communicate with another device on the same local network and knows the IP address but not the MAC address, it uses ARP to discover the MAC address.).

```
   getMacAddresses() {
    const cmd = "arp -a";
    const result = execSync(cmd, { encoding: "utf-8" });
    const devices = {};
    const lines = result.trim().split("\n").slice(3);

    for (const line of lines) {
      const [ip, mac] = line.split(/\s+/).filter(Boolean);
      devices[ip] = mac;
        }
    return devices;
  }
```

Finally using both the ip and the arp table, we can filter the client mac address.

The above code works only in the Nodejs and only when the API is called and the server and user should be on the same router.